# I am getting an error in my laravel site on shared hosting, the pages that have data coming from the db are giving me "500 server error"

Tags: laravel-8, shared-hosting

so i looked up a bunch of solutions but none seemed to work, also the errors in my cpanel also are not making sense to me, since im new to this hosting thing, the error in my cpanel Error section is :
[2022-01-18 12:07:00]: uid: (8524234/o0r1w0o4vp2j) gid: (8524234/o0r1w0o4vp2j) cmd: redirect.cgi
[2022-01-18 12:06:14]: uid: (8524234/o0r1w0o4vp2j) gid: (8524234/o0r1w0o4vp2j) cmd: redirect.cgi
[here is the image of my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gt8WS.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you have access to the web server logs of your site you can also check there for error messages and report back relevant error message(s) here.

Answer (score 0):

its seems that you have error, go to env file and chnage debug to true and you will see the error

Comment: thank you i'll look into it.